# How do I ensure a select change event fires AFTER ngmodel is set in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, select

I have a select element that has a basic (change) handler attached to it along with an ngmodel. When an `<option>` with a ng value is set, the change handler fires. The problem is that the [(ngModel] does not have the new values yet.

```
<div>
        <button style="margin: 8px 0;" (click)="getNextLink()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Next Label ></button>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="filter-word">Select Word To Filter:</label>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selectedLabels[selectedLabels.length]"
                    (change)="onChange($event)"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="filter-word"
                    name="filter-word">
                <option *ngFor="let label of (primaryTopic.topics) | stringFilter: selectedLabels" [ngValue]="label">
                    {{label}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the component code:

```
  public onChange(event: any): void {
    console.log('event', event);
    console.log('this.selectedLabels', this.selectedLabels); // undefined
    debugger; 
  }
```

How do I respond ONLY when the ngModel has been updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ngModelChange` instead:

```
(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
```

There is no way to specify in what order event handlers should be executed. Because `ngModelChange` is itself emitted  by `NgModel` after the bound property is updated, this should fit your needs.

Comment: Works exactly as one would expect. Thanks for the prompt response!